# Как выровнять виджет по центру родителя

Tags: css3, выравнивание

Не могу выровнять кнопку "Позвонить нам" по центру родительского элемента.
Или я совсем забыла css (что возможно, раз в полгода, в лучшем случае, стили поправляю на своем сайте), или дело в самом виджете от телефонии "Задарма".

Код такой:

В html перед закрывающим body вставляется это:

```
<div id="zadarmaScripts"></div>
    <script>
(function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://my.zadarma.com/callmewidget/v2.0.2/loader.js';
  document.getElementById('zadarmaScripts').appendChild(script);
  var script2 = document.createElement('script');
  script2.src = 'https://my.zadarma.com/callmewidget/languages/v1/ru.js';
  document.getElementById('zadarmaScripts').appendChild(script2);
}());
</script>
```

В css это:

```
#myZadarmaCallmeWidget359{
text-align: center;  
 }
```

В html, где должен отображаться виджет, это:

```
<p id="sv">Связаться со специалистом или оставить заявку на подбор
            варианта можно по</p>
          <p style="text-align: center;" id="contacts" itemprop="telephone">
            тел. (812) 123-тут номер телефона-123,</p>
          <p style="text-align: center;"> бесплатным звонком с сайта
            &nbsp;&nbsp; </p>
          <div id="myZadarmaCallmeWidget359" align="center";></div>
          <script>
  var myZadarmaCallmeWidget359;
  window.onload = function() {
    myZadarmaCallmeWidget359 = new ZadarmaCallmeWidget("myZadarmaCallmeWidget359");
    myZadarmaCallmeWidget359.create({
      "widgetId": "BvB1nz2b5h9vsuz8Ctfgca3rrB6FTNr1pVBmtbCsHfbYf6V9vyzh7nTst1f7E647bhF8m4eSzbjmu8Xc4YFyPP6Xkcx4Zp65b7a10cbede0102d18a1f0da6a9743909",       "sipId":"117461_0",       "domElement":"myZadarmaCallmeWidget359"     }, {       "shape":"square",       "width":"0",       "dtmf":false ,       "font": "'Trebuchet MS','Helvetica CY',sans-serif",       "color_call": "rgb(255, 255, 255)",       "color_bg_call": "rgb(126, 211, 33)",       "color_border_call": "rgb(191, 233, 144)",       "color_connection": "rgb(255, 255, 255)",       "color_bg_connection": "rgb(33, 211, 166)",       "color_border_connection": "rgb(144, 233, 211)",       "color_calling": "rgb(255, 255, 255)",       "color_border_calling": "rgb(255, 218, 128)",       "color_bg_calling": "rgb(255, 181, 0)",       "color_ended": "rgb(255, 255, 255)",       "color_bg_ended": "rgb(164,164,164)",       "color_border_ended": "rgb(210, 210, 210)"
    });
}
</script>
```

Родитель фрагмента кода html - просто div без своих стилей.
Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить косяк.
Спасибо

Comment: приведите код в порядок.

Comment: Что с ним не в порядке?

Comment: Исправила, вроде бы.

Comment: На so не принято ставить в заголовок вопроса слово "Решено" - вместо этого ставят галку на одном из ответов (он у вас один, собственный). Кажется, нужно будет подождать 2 дня в случае если хочется принять свой ответ, а не чужой.

Comment: Я для того и написала РЕШЕНО, чтобы не тратить время пользователей попусту. Уберу это слово из заголовка, когда можно будет принять ответ. А-а-а, уже модераторы его убрали...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решила задачу оборачиванием кода в тег center (html5)
Никакие другие меры не помогли  это сделать.

Вопрос закрыт.